# Apply value converter in XAML without databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, valueconverter

I have a TextBlock in my view that I want to always display the number 1, converted into the local currency. (e.g. $1 in US, £1 in UK, etc). I have a value converter that can do this, but I don't know how to apply a value converter to the value of 1 without getting my data from a databinding.

I can think of two solutions, but they each have their problems, and I'm looking for something more elegant:

1. Create a property on my ViewModel that just holds and returns the value 1 and bind to it. Then add my converter to this binding. This seems backwards, particularly as this is view-only code.
2. Make a binding point to an existing property and modify my converter to ignore the value given to it, and instead use the parameter to give it the number 1. This feels unintuitive to other programmers, as they'll be confused as to why I'm binding to a different property there.

Is there some way of applying a converter without first creating a binding?

Comment: Would `{Binding Source=1, Converter={whatever}}` work? I can't try it myself too easily at the moment..

Comment: It does work! I'd just put a slight error in my syntax. This is probably the most concise answer, although I still prefer decPL's as it cuts down a magic number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want for this to be relatively readable from XAML alone, you can always do it like this:

```
<Label>
   <Label.Resources>
      <system:Int32 x:Key="defaultValue">1</system:Int32>
   </Label.Resources>
   <Label.Content>
      <Binding Source="{StaticResource defaultValue}"
            Converter="{StaticResource CurrencyConverter}" />
   </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

Comment: Also, there's no need to use converter. Just write `StringFormat="c"`

Comment: @amnezjak True by all means, should have thought of that myself. This should be a standalone answer IMHO.

Comment: @NickUdell no it doesn't, using `StringFormat` you still need to provide the content of your label, it won't magically appear. I still agree that amnezjak's solution is better, but it doesn't cure cancer nor trim your garden :P

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation, I needed to convert static enum value placed directly in xaml to be converted by my custom converter without using databinding.

```
<Border>
    <Border.Background>
        <Binding Source="{x:Static enumeration:ColorType.Main}"
            Converter="{StaticResource ColorConverter}" />
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```